# Where to store an array of addresses?

Tags: solidity

I read about a couple of solutions for storing within the blockchain, but I was wondering what would be the best approach to storing an array of addresses that have bought an token. I want to be able to call this array and display it on my frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Constant functions don't require creating a transaction. Here is a simple getter/setter pattern:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.15;

contract Bought {
    address[] bought;

    // set the sender of the transaction as "bought" 
    function setBought()
    public
    {
        bought.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getAllBought()
    public
    constant // you will not need to make a transaction (i.e its free)
    returns(address[])
    {
        return bought;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to play with a fiddle, I made one here https://ethfiddle.com/5eSjmUkrF6

Comment: This answer is terrible. As soon as you have a good amount of addresses the gas fee would be immense. It could be infinity. Boo this man.